# Set the dynamic data in the angular universal application

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a location-based angular application which has been converted to universal application. Everything is working fine but there is a scenario for which I am looking for a workaround.

In my application customer has to select the location (latitude & longitude) and once selected that get stored in localStorage (not supported in SSR). Now in Universal APP I want to retain the location which user selected in cookie (it is supported in Nodejs and Angular) so when he comes next time it pick it from there.

If there is any other suggestion, I would be thankful.

Can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to save user data that must be accessible server side.

You can either interact directly with the cookies by injecting the Response and Request tokens in your components/services, but there aer 3rd party libs that make working with cookies easier, such as [ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service)

```
constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { 
  this.cookieService.set( 'Test', 'Hello World' );
  this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('Test');
}
```